# How to execute commandLink'actionListener function first then only execute JavaScript prompt?

Tags: javascript, jsf-2, facelets, managed-bean

Basically I have a list of records. Each record (the VO bean) will have an alert flag, `alertFlag`, attached to it. When the alertFlag is true, an alertbox will be prompt. Otherwise it wouldn't prompt.

The VO bean:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "theVo")
@SessionScoped
public class TheVO {
   private boolean alertFlag;

   /** getter and setter **/
}
```

Here is the XHTML code:

```
<t:dataTable var="theRecord" value="#{theVo.theList}">

  <t:column>
    <h:commandLink value="#{theRecord.recNo}" 
      actionListener="#{theEnquiry.doSetAlertFlag(theRecord.paramKey)}" 
      immediate="true" 
      action="#{theDetail.doShowDetailsPage(theRecord)}" 
      onclick="readAlertFlag(#{theEnquiry.alertFlag})"/>
    </h:commandLink>
  </t:column>

  ...
  ...
</t:dataTable>
```

Here is `theEnquiry` bean:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "theEnquiry")
@SessionScoped
public class Enquiry {

   private boolean alertFlag = false;

   /** getter and setter of alertFlag **/

   public void doSetAlertFlag(Integer theParamKey) {

      // check whether the alert flag is true or false.
      // if alert flag is true, otherwise set it false
   }
}
```

Here is the JavaScript code:

```
function readAlertFlag(alertFlag) {

  if( alertFlag == "true" )
    alert('alertFlag is true');
  else
    alert('alertFlag is false');
}
```

My current situation is the JavaScript alert box will always execute first then only  `doSetAlertFlag()` get executed. But my expectation is to execute `doSetAlertFlag()` first because I want the checking to be done first before prompting. If this can't be done on JavaScript prompt, I'm open to alternative solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let JSF render the script conditionally. Replace the `onclick` by a `<h:outputScript rendered>`.

```
<h:commandLink ... />
<h:outputScript rendered="#{theEnquiry.alertFlag}">showAlert()</h:outputScript>
```